# Sortby nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to sort a response data by a price property, the problem is that there are items that are defined as an array and each item has a price, I want the entire list to be sorted. My problem right now is dealing with type 2  (nested ng-repeat)
Currently Type 1 and 3 are display properly sorted and then Type 2 is not sorted.

HTML:

```
  <div class="flex-container row-cont">
        <div class="flex-container column prodlist">
            <ul>                
                <li ng-repeat="x in response.data | orderBy:sortprice">                                  
                    <div ng-if="x.type=='3'">
                        <div class="product flex-container row">
                                <div>{{x.price}}</div>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product flex-container row" ng if="x.type=='1'">
                            <div>{{x.fedex.price}}</div>                         
                    </div>
                    <div class="product flex-container row" ng-if="x.type=='2'" ng-repeat="obj in x.ups">                                
                            <div>{{obj.price}}</div>                                                                     
                    </div>
                </li>
```

javaScript:

```
    $scope.sortprice = function (item) {
        if (item.type == 1) {
            return item.fedex.price;
        }
        if (item.type == 2) {
            return ???;
        }
        if (item.type == 3) {
            return item.price;
        }
```

JSON:

```
({
  "fedex": {
    "creationDate": 1530110788904,
    "description": "loloo",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "product 1",
    "price": 10,
    "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/92c952",
    "url": "http://placehold.it/600/92c952"
  },
  "type": 1
},
 "type": 2,
  "ups": [
    {
      "creationDate": 1530110788904,
      "description": "fofofof",
      "id": 9,
      "name": "product 19",
      "price": 30,
      "thumbnailUrl": "lll.lll",
      "url": "http://ggg.ggg"
    },
    {
      "creationDate": 1530110788904,
      "description": "bdkdkkd",
      "id": 13,
      "name": "product 13",
      "price": 120,
      "url": "http://aaa.com"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "creationDate": 1530110788904,
  "deliveryComp": "dhl",
  "description": "officia delectus consequatur vero aut veniam explicabo molestias",
  "id": 7,
  "name": "product 7",
  "price": 14,
  "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/b0f7cc",
  "type": 3,
  "url": "http://placehold.it/600/b0f7cc"
},
{
  "type": 2,
  "ups": [
    {
      "creationDate": 1530110788904,
      "description": "qui eius qui autem sed",
      "id": 9,
      "name": "product 9",
      "price": 13,
      "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/51aa97",
      "url": "http://placehold.it/600/51aa97"
    },
    {
      "creationDate": 1530110788904,
      "description": "beatae et provident et ut vel",
      "id": 10,
      "name": "product 10",
      "price": 111,
      "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/810b14",
      "url": "http://placehold.it/600/810b14"
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Can you share how your json response looks like ? Want to understand type 2.

Comment: Yes no problem, I edited the question

Comment: Added my answer below, take a look and let me know how it goes. Or if you need something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
The solution didn't work well because I added a partial JSON question. There are many more type 2 items.in the first item the solution does work but in the second item the the solution is no longer relevant...

Comment: If the first solution in my post has solved your problem consider marking it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: The solution didn't work well , If you have any idea how to solve the problem, let me know, thanks

Comment: You added partial JSON and there are many more type2 items. Can you share the full json in that case and what do you mean by more type2 items ? Please elaborate..

Comment: The JSON is very long, I edited the question: I added one more item of type 2. When there is more than one item of type 2 the solution doesn't work well.

Comment: you mean, since there are various type2 objects, when the final result is displayed the entry type2 is not present at the right placed in the sorted list ?

Comment: can you plz confirm ?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: I updated my answer below. Have a look at the approach. IMO that solves the problem. I added a new attribute on each object as type sibling (named finalPrice). This is required to compare type2 kind of object with type1 during sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've structured it you'll always have the `type 2` products together because they're all handled at once in the inner `ng-repeat`. If that's desired, then the answer by @sagar-agrawal should work.

However if you intended `product 9` (price 13) to show before `product 7` (price 14) then you'll need to flatten your data for the purposes of this processing and have just one `ng-repeat`. It could be done like this:

```
//javascript
const combinedJson = [];
for (const data of json) {
  if (data.type === 2) {
    for (const innerData of data.ups) {
      combinedJson.push({type: 2, data: innerData, price: innerData.price});
    }
  }
  else {
    if (data.type == 3) {
      data.price = data.fedex.price;
    }
    combinedJson.push(data);
  }
}

$scope.sortprice = function (item) {
  return item.price;
};
```

Now `combinedJson` can be used in `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<ul>                
  <li ng-repeat="x in combinedJson | orderBy:sortprice">
    <div class="product flex-container row">
      <div>{{x.price}}</div>                          
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be simple. The sort method you wrote, you want the middle if condition (i.e. for type=2) because its an array. So this method should return the largest price in the array, right? You can write something like this. You should call this function before displaying it on html, just after you got response from the api.

```
$scope.sortItems = function(responseObj){
   var output;
   for(item in responseObj){
      if(item.type == 1){
         item.finalPrice = item.fedex.price;
      }
      else if(item.type == 2){
         item.ups.sort(function(a, b){ return b.price - a.price });
         item.finalPrice = item.ups[0].price;
      }
      else{
        item.finalPrice = item.price;
      }
   }
}
//The above method will add a new attribute name finalPrice denoting the prices. For type2, the max price of all objects in ups will be taken. So this will make sure we're comparing prices across all types.
```

And the upper div, you can sort the items based on finalPrice using orderBy pipe. IMO you don't need the sort function also anymore.

```
<li ng-repeat="x in response.data | orderBy:finalPrice">                                  
                <div> <!--You dont need to check type=1 or 3 anymore as all the data has finalPrice attribute. -->
                    <div class="product flex-container row">
                            <div>{{x.finalPrice}}</div>                          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="product flex-container row">
                        <div>{{x.finalPrice}}</div>                         
                </div>
                <div class="product flex-container row" ng-if="x.type=='2'" ng-repeat="obj in x.ups">                                
                        <div>{{obj.price}}</div>                                                                     
                </div>
            </li>
```

Each object is having a new attribute as finalPrice. The type2 is also having an attribute as type2 sibling which will be the max value of all the objects in its ups array. So now you can do sorting on finalPrice. This should solve the problem.

Comment: I hope you got the idea of how this approach will work.